# How to fix overfilled 1-gang switch box?

Tags: electrical, wiring, aluminum-wiring, overflow

I have a 1-gang electrical box for a lightswitch. Because of how the room was historically wired it has a lot of cables coming into it. It has the following romex wires coming into/out of it:

- Home run (comes in from top of box)
- wires to other outlets in the room (this goes out the top of the box)
- wires to an outlet that used to be switched by the switch (goes out bottom)
- wires to an overhead light that is now switched by the switch. (also goes out top)

Additionally, these wires are aluminum so, as my understanding goes, they require to be connected (following appropriate procedures, torque, etc.) using Alumiconn connectors and making connections to the switch using copper pigtails. Since there are 4 neutrals and 4 hots I actually require 2 alumicons each for neutrals and hot. This takes up a lot of volume

Right now this is stuffed into what I would call a "standard" size switch box which probably has about 18 cu in of volume or so (I haven't carefully determined it) which is way below the volume required as per overfill calculations for the wiring I mentioned above. The wiring above requires at least 25 cu in, I could calculate more carefully to get a definitive answer. There are also currently wire nuts where there need to be Alumiconns which really motivates me to want to upgrade the wiring.

In any case, I'm aware of concerns and how to remedy them for aluminum wiring, I'm also aware of the code for box fill and that I'm above the fill for my box. What I'm not sure about is the best strategy for fixing the problem but I do have a few ideas. The switch is in a shallow wall so there isn't really room for a deeper box.

- Get some sort of old work 1-gang box that has extra storage volume behind the drywall. Something like the picture below, except the picture is new work box. Unfortunately I haven't been able to find a part in my local hardware store or even online that satisfies what I'm looking for..
- Use a 2-gang box and put a "blank" in one of the slots so that there is just a big box to work in.
- The box has so many wires in it because it was historically used as a junction for the outlets and in a different way. Maybe the room could be a little re-wired to reflect this. One possibility would be to put a junction box with a blank faceplate a little distance above the switch. This junction box would have the home run come in and the wiring to the other outlets, and a new copper wire stretch going to the switch box. The switch box would then split power to the switched overhead light and the outlet which used to be switched.
- Both the home run and the wiring to the "other outlets" enters the wall from the attic above through a hole that I have access to. Maybe I could install a junction box up in the attic instead of using a face plate in the wall? There is insulation over the area in the attic.

The other piece of relevant information is that this is a room on the main floor of a one-story house and I have pretty easy access to the some of the wires coming in from the attic above. Otherwise I'm trying to avoid having to do drywall repairs but I'm prepared to do them if need be. Also I'm pretty much not considering re-wiring anything with copper wires at this point.

Is there an easy natural approach I haven't put up here? Are there compelling reasons to choose one of the approaches above? I'm leaning towards using the 2-gang box since it seems like it would be the most straightforward but I'm worried that it would look strange in the room. Would this be a "standard" solution?

[image]

Comment: MAC Block connectors can connect 0-4 aluminum to 0-4 copper wires.  Or up to 8 of any single metal.   (Well it has 2 voids, each UL-listed for up to 4 wires of one  metal type).  Much better option than chaining Alumiconns.  Are you married to plastic boxes?

Comment: Ideal brand also has aluminum rated wire nuts. For boxes with a large fill I go to deep metal 4-0 boxes with a mud ring, plastic will work but larger wire and the quantity of wires may warp a plastic box.  Since you did not show your actual box fill calculation be aware that for the 2020 code, fill on your grounds has changed, if under the NEC. The ground now count for 1x of the wire size for the first 4. After the first 4 are 1x  that they are 1/4x each for the wire size. Note a mud ring can turn a 2 gang box into a single gang opening also picking up more space. The mud ring makes it look ok